# How to insert an indentation check into the operator precedence parser?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I am working on the parsing stage for the language I am making and am having difficulty with the following.

```
let test2 = // I'd like this to be an error.
    """
    2 
   + 2
    """

let result = run (spaces >>. expr) test2

val result : ParserResult<CudaExpr,unit> =
  Success: Add (LitInt32 2,LitInt32 2)
```

I already managed to make the following example when the terms are indented incorrectly

```
 2 +
2
```

give me an error, but not when the operator is on the wrong indentation level. I need something like a before-parse check.

```
let operators expr i =
    let f expr (s: CharStream<_>) = if i <= s.Column then expr s else pzero s
    opp.TermParser <- f expr
    f opp.ExpressionParser
```

The above function is how the operators phase is structured and as you can see, the term parsers get wrapped in a function that does the indentation check, but the last line is faulty.

Here is a simplified example of the full parser.

```
#r "../../packages/FParsec.1.0.2/lib/net40-client/FParsecCS.dll"
#r "../../packages/FParsec.1.0.2/lib/net40-client/FParsec.dll"

open FParsec

type Expr = 
    | V of string
    | Add of Expr * Expr

let identifier = many1Satisfy2L isAsciiLetter (fun x -> isAsciiLetter x || isDigit x || x = ''') "identifier" .>> spaces |>> V

let indentations expressions (s: CharStream<_>) =
    let i = s.Column
    let expr_indent expr (s: CharStream<_>) =
        let expr (s: CharStream<_>) = if i <= s.Column then expr s else pzero s
        many1 expr s

    expr_indent (expressions i) s

let expr =
    let opp = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>()
    opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("+", spaces, 6, Associativity.Left, fun x y -> Add(x,y)))

    let operators expr i =
        let f (s: CharStream<_>) = if i <= s.Column then expr s else pzero s
        opp.TermParser <- f
        f opp.ExpressionParser

    let rec expr s = indentations (operators identifier) s

    expr

let test2 = // I'd like this to be an error.
    """
    a 
   + 
    b 
    """

let result = run (spaces >>. expr) test2
```

The full parser so far can be found [here](https://github.com/mrakgr/Multi-armed-Bandit-Experiments/blob/master/Spiral%20V5/V5%20With%20The%20New%20Backend/SpiralV5Parser_v1e.fsx).

Comment: I imagine you'd want to leverage [user state](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-with-user-state.html) to keep track of the indentation level of the terms of your expression, and then check that it's consistent when you parse an operator or another term.

Comment: I considered it, but I found this way to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
let operators expr i =
    let f (s: CharStream<_>) = if i <= s.Column then expr s else pzero s
    opp.TermParser <- f
    f opp.ExpressionParser
```

I did not realize it 2.5 weeks ago, but what happens when a new block gets opened and `expr s` gets called is that the term parser gets overwritten with the new indentation and there is no way to back it up and restore it on exit. I did a bit of looking around and managed to adapt the Pratt top down parsing method for my purposes.

Here is [a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e_oEE72d3U) by Douglas Crockford on the method.

```
let poperator: Parser<_,_> =
    let f c = (isAsciiIdContinue c || isAnyOf [|' ';'\t';'\n';'\"';'(';')';'{';'}';'[';']'|] c) = false
    (many1Satisfy f .>> spaces)
    >>= fun token ->
        match dict_operator.TryGetValue token with
        | true, x -> preturn x
        | false, _ -> fail "unknown operator"

let rec led poperator term left (prec,asoc,m) =
    match asoc with
    | Associativity.Left | Associativity.None -> tdop poperator term prec |>> m left
    | Associativity.Right -> tdop poperator term (prec-1) |>> m left
    | _ -> failwith "impossible"

and tdop poperator term rbp =
    let rec f left =
        poperator >>= fun (prec,asoc,m as v) ->
            if rbp < prec then led poperator term left v >>= loop
            else pzero
    and loop left = attempt (f left) <|>% left
    term >>= loop

let operators expr i (s: CharStream<_>) =
    let expr_indent expr (s: CharStream<_>) = expr_indent i (<=) expr s
    let op s = expr_indent poperator s
    let term s = expr_indent expr s
    tdop op term 0 s
```

The `led` and `tdop` functions which do the actual precedence parsing are 10 lines long. The above is just a snippet of the [full parser](https://github.com/mrakgr/Multi-armed-Bandit-Experiments/blob/db25dc11ea96f52ff84e0e72f2cadbe21349cbe8/Spiral%20V5/V5%20With%20The%20New%20Backend/SpiralV5Parser_v2a.fsx) for the language I am making - in terms of syntax it is similar to F# and is indentation sensitive. Here is a more straightforward [F# translation](https://github.com/mrakgr/Multi-armed-Bandit-Experiments/blob/db25dc11ea96f52ff84e0e72f2cadbe21349cbe8/Spiral%20V5/V5%20With%20The%20New%20Backend/Top%20Down%20Operator%20Parsers/tdop_v1b.fsx) of Douglas Crockford's [Javascript example](https://github.com/douglascrockford/TDOP).